# Table with alternate backround rows and header

Tags: html, css

I use css to make my rows alternate like this:
[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SaQk9/2/)

```
tr:nth-child(odd) td   { background-color:red; }
tr:nth-child(even) td   { background-color:blue; }
tr th { background-color: yellow}

table {
    border: 1px solid black;
    margin: 10px;
    width: 100px;
    }
```

Some tables have headers, and some tables do not. The data always needs start with red, but when a table has a header, its row is counted as first row and data starts with blue instead. Is there any way to make it always start with red?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

#### Use `<tbody>` and `<thead>`

Use `<tbody>` and put all the body rows in it. Also, wrap your header inside `<thead>`. Updated CSS below:

```
tbody tr:nth-child(odd) td   { background-color:red; }
tbody tr:nth-child(even) td   { background-color:blue; }
thead tr th { background-color: yellow}
```

This way you will be targeting only the data rows and not header rows. Hope this helps you...

#### Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/praveenscience/TQgjC/